# is there an application to manage bookmarks?

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, applications, bookmarks

I hate the in-built book mark managers of all browsers, it quickly becomes too messy and important links are hard to find

Is there desktop application which deal with bookmarks? something that has multiple options of fitters: categories, folders, tags and more

For example the task manager, omnifocus, is as simple or as complex as you want it to be, is there anything like that for bookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers posted here, I suggest looking at a few different online bookmarking sites:

- http://diigo.com
- http://pinboard.in
- (and yes) Delicious.com

Most of these services have add-ons or extensions to access the bookmarks. :)

(I really like diigo.com)

Comment: +1 for Diigo!! I would highly (highly!) recommend it to you. I wish I could +10 it. :-)

Comment: i'll try all of them, so far I like diigo, delicious is great (I use that) but I am looking for more - pinboard seems to not be free AT ALL- so Diigo it is

Comment: You are absolutely right, Pinboard.in is **not** free, but it is pretty reliable and the emphasis for Pinboard.in is to be simple and ad-free. Diigo strikes a nice balance of being full featured, free and not too "ad-annoying". Good luck! (By the way, I use Xmarks to sync local bookmarks, but use Diigo to store general bookmarks that I like sharing with others.)

Comment: For those of you looking to sync bookmarks over different browsers on your Mac and have the time to really experiment, I suggest: [BookMacster] (http://www.sheepsystems.com/products/bookmacster.html) The interface is a little confusing, but once you have it up and running, it is bookmark synchronization bliss. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com). It stores the bookmarks on an Xmarks-server, so they are available from everywhere. It's compatible with Safari, IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Xmarks also lets you sync bookmarks across different computers, both Macs and PCs, on most browsers. Since I sometimes need to move among a Mac and several PCs in the course of a day, this is really useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [URL Manager Pro](http://www.url-manager.com/). It's been around for a very long time, and is still under active development. It has received excellent reviews. It's Lion-compatible, and is also available in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I created a different kind of bookmarking app for Mac: http://fetching.io

In addition to all the bookmarking features, it saves a full copy of every web page you visit then let's you easily search your index to re-find pages later. It' a totally different way of doing things. You don't have to remember to save anything since everything is saved and super easy to find later, even months or years later.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for disclosing your affiliation with the product you are promoting. Don't forget to see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).